# ElasticSearch. How to produce "$in" with QueryBuilders

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have code:

```
List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = boolQuery();
queryBuilder.must(matchQuery("field", values));
```

I need search in Elastic like this  query in mongo:

```
{
     field : {'$in' : values}
}
```

How to do this with Elastic?  My code search in last item in List values.

UPDATE (found solution myself, thanks all):

```
queryBuilder.must(termsQuery("field", values));
```

Comment: you mean search by multi field, isnt it?

Answer (score 0):

Check the terms filter:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-filter.html

```
{
    "constant_score" : {
        "filter" : {
            "terms" : { "user" : ["kimchy", "elasticsearch"]}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Used "termsQuery" instead of "matchQuery" :

```
queryBuilder.must(termsQuery("field", values));
```